# SQL JSON multiply CROSS APPLY

Tags: json, sql-server

I have the following code which is used to search the contents of a JSON column for the id values. The code works great and in this case returns 6 rows.

```
SELECT log
FROM logs
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([log], '$.tags') WITH (id INT '$.id')
WHERE id = 12
```

I tried extending the search to another column using the following code

```
SELECT *
FROM logs
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([log_x], '$.tags') WITH (id_x INT '$.id')
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([log_y], '$.tags') WITH (id_y INT '$.id')
WHERE id_x = 1
```

This returns 16 values as it creates duplicated rows. Does anyone know how to combine multiple "cross apply" without creating the duplicates?

Below is some example code that i have been using to create the tables

```
INSERT INTO A10000000075.dbo.Logs ([log_x], [log_y])
VALUES ('{"tags":[{"id_x":1,"x":99.12343123213,"y":88.123232},{"id_x":12,"x":99.12343123213,"y":88.123232},{"id_x":13,"x":99.12343123213,"y":88.123232}]}',
'{"tags":[{"id_y":1006,"x":99.12343123213,"y":88.123232},{"id_y":12,"x":99.12343123213,"y":88.123232},{"id_y":13,"x":99.12343123213,"y":88.123232}]}');
```

Comment: Is that not simply modifying the first query to `where id in (1, 12)`? Or what result are you trying to get?

Comment: Give example input data and desired results. It is not clear why you are getting duplicates or how you want the results alternatively presented

Comment: WHERE id_x = id_y AND (id_x = 12 OR id_y = 1) ?

Comment: Thanks but using the CROSS APPLY twice I get an entire column where every single row has the value of 1

Comment: The example provided has only [log] and [logy]. What is [log_x] and [log_y] in your select then? Could you please show actual schema of "logs" table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try this:

```
SELECT a.[id_x],a.[id_y]
FROM (
    SELECT TRY_CONVERT(INT,JSON_VALUE(x.value,'$.id_x')) AS [id_x]
        ,TRY_CONVERT(INT,JSON_VALUE(y.value,'$.id_y')) AS [id_y]
    FROM logs
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([log_x], '$.tags') AS x
    CROSS APPLY OPENJSON([log_y], '$.tags') AS y
    WHERE x.[key] = y.[key]
) a
WHERE a.id_x = 1
;
```

Comment: Thank you but it didnt work. As soon as I added another search criteria WHERE a.id_x = 1 OR a.id_y = 1 i get no results. I will have a think about this and see if i can ammend your solution.

Comment: I had a few null values that had prevented the results showing. Thank you for all your help

Comment: You can use OUTER APPLY and extend WHERE condition to handle NULL values